# Add an HTML linking CSS buttons to another SP site

Tags: 2013, css, html

I am pretty green to using CSS & HTML to customize sites within SharePoint.  I created buttons & I am now trying to create a hyperlink for those buttons to navigate to another SharePoint site. I need to have the button when clicked to open a SharePoint site based on its URL.  I have added this into a Content editor webpart that links to my SharePoint Code doc library.

```
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .button {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 4px;
   background-color: #1E90FF;
   border: none;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 200px;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
 }
 .button span {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   transition: 0.5s;
 }
 .button span:after {
   content: '\00bb';
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
   transition: 0.5s;
 }
 .button:UTM span {
   padding-right: 25px;
 }
 .button:UTM span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;}
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <button class="button" style="verticalalign:middle"><span>UTM   </span></button>
```

Comment: please add your current code

Comment: @M.Qassas I have edited the original question to include the code

Comment: DO you need to have a link button to navigate you to another SharePoint site from the current page

Comment: I don't necessarily HAVE to include a link button.  I just prefer the look/feel of a button rather than a plain underlined word & link.

Comment: Okay, no problem, but your question still unclear, please confirm your requirements, you now have the above HTML code and you need let the above button when it clicked open a SharePoint site based on its URL, Right?

Comment: Exactly! I'll be sure to be more specific in my question next time.

Comment: Okay could you please edit your question again with your requirements to reopen it again and can members help you, I also will try to provide to you answer once you edit your question with some details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `input` control with `type="button"` and at `onclick` event go to your SharePoint Site.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://yourSharePoint URL';" value="Go to SharePoint Site" class="button" style="verticalalign:middle" />
```

**Alternative solution**

```
<script>
    function visitsite(){
        window.location='http://yourSharePoint';
    }
</script>
<button class="button" style="verticalalign:middle" onclick="visitsite();">Visit SP Site</button>
```

Comment: So, I input the alternative solution you submitted into a script editor web part, just to try it out to see if both would work.  The code works works within the script editor. But then when I go to insert it onto the site.  The button then does not work anymore. Any thoughts on why?  Do I need to be doing this in SharePoint Designer to be more effective?

Comment: @SHARE.Newb Do you tried to use the first solution? by the way, what do you mean with "when I go to insert it onto the site"?

Comment: @SHARE.Newb When it worked for you, please don't forget to **Mark** this answer as accepted to be helpful for future visitors. Thank You!